# Create a separate git repository fpr deployment using an existing working tree

Tags: git

I have a git repo A with it's working directory A. For deployment I would like to setup a separated git repo B in which I can track only part of the files that I track in my working tree repo A (e.g. using a different .gitignore file). The deployment git repo B should track the changes in the working tree A but should not be aware of the git repo A.
--separate-git-dir and git worktre ... didn't work or at least I was not able to make it work the way I need it.

The idea is to make diffs in the git repo B, send this to the customer and apply the diff there.

Comment: Why don't you just rsync it then ?

Comment: Creating another `Git` repository for deployment is probably not the best approach. I suggest you starting with a well-configured `rsync` (read the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) about the include and exclude patterns) then gradually develop it to a deploy script that also generates (or copies from a separate location) the configuration files for production, runs `composer install` (if the project uses `composer` to manage its dependencies), clear and/or warmup the cache and so on.